# how to hide a div container if input dynamically added with choice in checkbox are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to hide a div container if input dynamically added with choice in checkbox are empty

So here what I looked on the forums but I did not find a subject similar to mine

As I explained, I created a booking form for an evening with dynamic inputs to choose on a checkbox

example: I choose the number of adults / number of children and depending on the number of inputs created creates appear ... until all is well ...

I add a PayPal object api (dynamic payment method depending on choice) from their site

what I would like to do

option 1: it is a "required" on the inputs if the fields are all filled the PayPal button (which is a div) gets gray

or

option 2: hide the button if empty input.

Friends if you could give me a hand this would be super nice thank you !!

```js
/* set global variable i */

var i=0;
const adult_price = 20;
const child_price = 10;


/* 
---------------------------------------------

function to remove fom elements dynamically

---------------------------------------------
*/
function updateIds(type) {
 
 if ( type == "adult" ) {
  var j=1; 
  
  // Replace all id_adult_x by id_adult_j, with "j" an ordered list starting with j=1  
  $('[id^=id_adult_]').each(function() {
   
   // Replace the LABEL text 
   document.getElementById("lbl_"+this.id).innerHTML = "<hr>"+"Adulte"+" "+j;

   var res = this.id.split("id_adult_").join('');  
   var spanContent = document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML; 
   var strToReplace = new RegExp('_adult_'+res, "gi");
   
   document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = spanContent.replace( strToReplace, '_adult_'+j);
   
   this.id = "id_adult_"+j;
   j= ++j;
  });
  
 } else if ( type == "child" ) {
     var j=1; 
 
  $('[id^=id_child_]').each(function() {
   
   // Replace the LABEL text 
   document.getElementById("lbl_"+this.id).innerHTML = "<hr>"+"Enfant"+" "+j;
   var res = this.id.split("id_child_").join('');  
   var spanContent = document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML; 
   var strToReplace = new RegExp('_child_'+res, "gi");
   
   document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = spanContent.replace( strToReplace, '_child_'+j);
  
   this.id = "id_child_"+j;
   j= ++j;
  });
  
 }
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------

function to remove fom elements dynamically

---------------------------------------------^
*/
function removeElement(parentDiv, childDiv){

    if (childDiv == parentDiv) {
        alert("The parent div cannot be removed.");
    }
    else if (document.getElementById(childDiv)) {    
  var child = document.getElementById(childDiv);
        var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
        parent.removeChild(child);
  
  if (childDiv.includes("adult")) {
   document.getElementById("nbrAdult").value = $("[id^=id_adult_]").length ;
   
   // Calculate the new total price
   setTotalPrice();

   // Update IDs 
   updateIds("adult");   
  } 
  else if (childDiv.includes("child")) {
   document.getElementById("nbrChild").value = $("[id^=id_child_]").length ;
   
   // Calculate the new total price
   setTotalPrice();

   // Update IDs 
   updateIds("child");
  } 
  else {
   /* do nothing */
  }
    }
    else {
        alert("Child div has already been removed or does not exist.");
        return false;
    }
}

 
 /* 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 functions that will be called upon, when user change the list "Nombre Adulte(s)"
 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function onAdultChange()
{
// Retrieve the number of "Adult" selected by the user
var nbrAdultValue = document.getElementById("nbrAdult").value;

// Count the total number of "Adult" Div that are actually created on the html file  
var idAdultCount = $("[id^=id_adult_]").length; 

// Calculate the delta btw these variables, in order to create or delete the right number of "Adult" Div
var x = nbrAdultValue - idAdultCount;

// Check if the delta is negative, if so, we must delete the last "x" number of "Adult" Div
if ( x < 0 ) {
 // Convert "x" from negative to absolute 
 x = Math.abs(x); 
 // alert("This action will remove last "+x+" Adult Fields");
 
 // Remove the last "x" "Adult" Div 
 for (j = 0; j < x ; j++) { 
  var max = 0;
  $("[id^=id_adult_]").each(function() { 
   var res = this.id.split("id_adult_").join('');
   max = Math.max(res, max); 
  });
  
  removeElement("myForm","id_adult_"+max);
 }  
} 
else { 
 // Create "x" new "Adult" Div
 for (j = 0; j < x; j++) { 
  i = ++i;





  var r = document.createElement('span');
  r.setAttribute("id", "id_adult_"+i);
  document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
  



  var l = document.createElement("LABEL");
  l.setAttribute("id", "lbl_id_adult_"+i);
  l.innerHTML = "Adulte "+i;
  document.getElementById("id_adult_"+i).appendChild(l);

  lastNameFunction("adult_"+i);
  firstNameFunction("adult_"+i);
        emailFunction("adult_"+i);
  telFunction("adult_"+i);


        var g = document.createElement("IMG");
  g.setAttribute("src", "delete.jpg");
  g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_adult_"+ i +"')");
  document.getElementById("id_adult_"+i).appendChild(g);


  
 }
}

// Calculate the new total price
setTotalPrice();

// Update IDs 
updateIds("adult");

}
                      
                        
 /* 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 functions that will be called upon, when user change the list "Nombre Enfant(s)"
 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function onChildChange()
{
 
// Retrieve the number of "Child" selected by the user
var nbrChildValue = document.getElementById("nbrChild").value;

// Count the total number of "Child" Div that are actually created on the html file  
var idChildCount = $("[id^=id_child_]").length; 

// Calculate the delta btw these variables, in order to create or delete the right number of "Child" Div
var x = nbrChildValue - idChildCount;

// Check if the delta is negative, if so, we must delete the last "x" number of "Child" Div
if ( x < 0 ) {
 // Convert "x" from negative to absolute 
 x = Math.abs(x); 
 // alert("This action will remove last "+x+" Child Fields");
 
 // Remove the last "x" "Child" Div 
 for (j = 0; j < x ; j++) { 
  var max = 0;
  $("[id^=id_child_]").each(function() { 
   var res = this.id.split("id_child_").join('');
   max = Math.max(res, max); 
  });
  
  removeElement("myForm","id_child_"+max);
 }  
} 
else { 
 // Create "x" new "Child" Div
 for (j = 0; j < x; j++) { 
  i = ++i;
  var r = document.createElement('span');
  r.setAttribute("id", "id_child_"+i);
  document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(r);
  
  var l = document.createElement("LABEL");
  l.setAttribute("id", "lbl_id_child_"+i);
  l.innerHTML = "Enfant "+i;
  document.getElementById("id_child_"+i).appendChild(l);

  lastNameFunction("child_"+i);
  firstNameFunction("child_"+i);

  var g = document.createElement("IMG");
  g.setAttribute("src", "delete.jpg");
  g.setAttribute("onclick", "removeElement('myForm','id_child_"+ i +"')");
  document.getElementById("id_child_"+i).appendChild(g);
 }
}

// Calculate the new total price
setTotalPrice();
 
// Update IDs 
updateIds("child");
}


 /* 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 functions that will create an input field for the lastName
 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function lastNameFunction(type)
{
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
y.setAttribute("id","nom-de-famille");
y.setAttribute("placeholder","Nom");
y.setAttribute("Name","lastname_"+type);
document.getElementById("id_"+type).appendChild(y);
document.getElementById("nom-de-famille").required=true;
}
  



 /* 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 functions that will create an input field for the firstName
 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function firstNameFunction(type)
{
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "text");
y.setAttribute("placeholder","Prenom");
y.setAttribute("Name","firstname_"+type);
document.getElementById("id_"+type).appendChild(y);
}

 /* 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 functions that will create an input field for the Email
 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function emailFunction(type)
{
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "email");
y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Email");
y.setAttribute("Name","email_"+type);
document.getElementById("id_"+type).appendChild(y);
}

 /* 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
 functions that will create an input field for the phone number
 
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function telFunction(type)
{
var y = document.createElement("INPUT");
y.setAttribute("type", "tel");
y.setAttribute("placeholder", "Tel");
y.setAttribute("Name","tel_"+type);
document.getElementById("id_"+type).appendChild(y);
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------

function that calculate the total price 

---------------------------------------------
*/
function setTotalPrice()
{
  document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = document.getElementById("nbrAdult").value*adult_price + document.getElementById("nbrChild").value*child_price;
}


/* 
---------------------------------------------

function that create the Items List formatted for Paypal 

---------------------------------------------
*/
function getJsonItemsList()
{   
 var itemsList = [];

 var j=0;
 
 $('[id^=id_adult_]').each(function() {
  itemsList.push({ "name":"Adulte "+(j+1) , "description": document.getElementsByName
   ("lastname_adult_"+(j+1))[0].value 
       + " " + document.getElementsByName("firstname_adult_" 
    +(j+1))[0].value + " " + document.getElementsByName  
         ("email_adult_"+(j+1))[0].value
       + " " + document.getElementsByName("tel_adult_"
     +(j+1))[0].value , "quantity": "1", "price": + adult_price , "currency":"EUR" });
           j= ++j;
 });
 
 var h=0;
 
 $('[id^=id_child_]').each(function() {
  itemsList.push({ "name":"Enfant "+(h+1) ,
   "description": document.getElementsByName("lastname_child_"+(h+1))[0].value 
   + " " + document.getElementsByName("firstname_child_"+(h+1))[0].value , "quantity": "1", "price": 
   + child_price , "currency":"EUR" });
  h= ++h;
 });
 
 if ( j == "0" && h == "0") { 
  itemsList ="' '"; 
 }
 
 return itemsList ; 
}

/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

functions  that will be called upon, when user click on the Reset Button

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function resetElements(){
document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById("nbrAdult").value = "0";
document.getElementById("nbrChild").value = "0";
document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = "0";
i = 0;
}
```

```css
    
  .three {
    width: 80%;
    border: solid 1px lightgray;
    margin-top: 30px ;
    margin-bottom: 30px ;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  
  .jta-before-form {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .jta-form-layout {
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  
  #mainform > .jta-form-content {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  #myForm {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  input {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 20px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  input:focus {
    background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
 
  #lbl_id_adult_1,
  #lbl_id_adult_2,
  #lbl_id_adult_3,
  #lbl_id_adult_4,
  #lbl_id_adult_5,
  #lbl_id_adult_6,
  #lbl_id_adult_7,
  #lbl_id_adult_8,
  #lbl_id_adult_9 {
   margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px ;
  border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
    display: block; 
  }
  
  #id_adult_1> img,
  #id_adult_2> img,
  #id_adult_3> img,
  #id_adult_4> img,
  #id_adult_5> img,
  #id_adult_6> img,
  #id_adult_7> img,
  #id_adult_8> img,
  #id_adult_9 > img {
    float: right;
}
  
  #lbl_id_child_1,
  #lbl_id_child_2,
  #lbl_id_child_3,
  #lbl_id_child_4,
  #lbl_id_child_5,
  #lbl_id_child_6,
  #lbl_id_child_7,
  #lbl_id_child_8,
  #lbl_id_child_9 {
   margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px ;
  border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
    display: block; 
  }
  
  #id_child_1> img,
  #id_child_2> img,
  #id_child_3> img,
  #id_child_4> img,
  #id_child_5> img,
  #id_child_6> img,
  #id_child_7> img,
  #id_child_8> img,
  #id_child_9 > img {
    float: right;
  }

  #totalPrice {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #paypal-button-container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>



<html>
<head>
<title>Create Dynamic form Using JavaScript - Demo Preview</title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />

<script src="js/repas-annuel-form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form-style.css">  
</head>
<body>
<div class ="main_content">



<div class="three">

     <div class="jta-before-form">
         <span id="jta-form-title" class="jta-form-title">
      <h3>reservation</h3></span>
     <div class="">Les champs marqués d’un astérisque * sont obligatoires</div>
    </div>
<div class="jta-form-layout">
 <form action="#" type="sbubmit" method="get" id="mainform" >
     <div class="jta-before-form-content" >

   
   
    <div class="label" >
    <label for="nbrAdult" >Nombre Adulte(s)</label>
    </div>
    <select id="nbrAdult" onchange="onAdultChange()">
     <option value="0" selected=>0</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
   </div>

   
    <div class="label">
    <label for="nbrChild">Nombre Enfant(s)</label>
    </div>

    <select id="nbrChild" onchange="onChildChange()" >
     <option value="" >0</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
     <option value="5">5</option>
     <option value="6">6</option>
     <option value="7">7</option>
     <option value="8">8</option>
     <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jta-form-content ">
   <span id="myForm"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="jta-after-form-content">Prix Total (Euro)
   <INPUT id="totalPrice" type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="0" Size=8></INPUT>
  </div>
 </form>
<div class="jta-after-form">
 <div name="button-paypal" id="paypal-button-container"></div>
  <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
  <script>  
   // Render the PayPal button
   paypal.Button.render({
   // Set your environment
   env: 'production', // sandbox | production

   // Specify the style of the button
   style: {
     layout: 'vertical',  // horizontal | vertical
     size:   'medium',    // medium | large | responsive
     shape:  'pill',      // pill | rect
     color:  'silver'       // gold | blue | silver | white | black
   },

   // Specify allowed and disallowed funding sources
   //
   // Options:
   // - paypal.FUNDING.CARD
   // - paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT
   // - paypal.FUNDING.ELV
   funding: {
     allowed: [
    paypal.FUNDING.CARD,
     
     ],
     disallowed: [
    paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT,
     ], 
   },

   // Enable Pay Now checkout flow (optional)
   commit: true,

   // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
   // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
   client: {
     sandbox: 'AXnE7qNrnFxL4IsXrCSFP_mQPvjPNdGo_UA1pHvcw0p_hnmrLQR3_XOlqRTGe7POwHj8urXcd1DmmwWo',
     production: 'Afe_0oViyEcryagJtFBf34Gkf_hbTgsIjPBkCKIdyD5jYNQF_Kyu3s1nawS46kTMBRoT25STeSnNkFF7'
   },
  
   // Set up a payment
   payment: function(data, actions) {
     return actions.payment.create({
    transactions: [{
      amount: {

       total:    document.getElementById("totalPrice").value,currency: 'EUR'},
               
         description: 'Reservation - Repas Annuel 2018.',

         item_list: { items: getJsonItemsList() } 
    }],
    note_to_payer: 'Contact us for any questions on your order.'
     });
   },         

   
   onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
     return actions.payment.execute()
    .then(function () {
      window.alert('Merci pour votre réservation !');
    });
   }
   }, '#paypal-button-container');

  </script>


</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are actually many discussions and tutorials on this topic. Simply search for "javascript validate form". The dynamic aspect of your form shouldn't matter so much, as your validator function should just re-scan your entire form every time.

Comment: The validator function should be called anytime there's form activity (a change to any form element), and ultimately when the form is in a "pass" state then you can activate your pay button. Also, you shouldn't hide your pay button... instead give it some inactive styling so people know about it. If they click it, then you give them a message about form corrections. But hiding the button from the start is more confusing.

Comment: `</script>
</script>` script in script that is not good, possible malformed example html there.

Comment: You have TWO different versions of jQuery there in the header.  Perhaps take a minute to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok boss sorry i'm begginer ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to go out on a limb here and say all this ID management is pretty messy, difficult to maintain and frankly really unnecessary here.  Use classes instead and make life a lot simpler for yourself.

- I modified your markup to use a pair of hidden cloned input groups that I append to the form.
- I removed a good bit of excess code - still pretty verbose but that is to allow you to see what is happening on each action.
- I did NOT wire up the reset but that should be easy if you have the button somewhere.
- I removed a good bit of markup for extra jQuery and unknown js etc.
- I found and fixed a few (more than a few maybe) typos as well.

```js
/* set global variable i */
//var i = 0;
const adult_price = 20;
const child_price = 10;

/* 
---------------------------------------------
function to remove form elements dynamically
---------------------------------------------
*/
function updateIds() {
  let adults = ".adult-container";
  let children = ".child-container"
  let containers = $('#myForm').find('.container-group');
  containers.each(function() {
    let containerDiv = $(this);
    let idx = 0;
    if (containerDiv.is(adults)) {
      idx = $(adults).index($(this)) + 1;
    }
    if (containerDiv.is(children)) {
      idx = $(children).index($(this)) + 1;
    }
    containerDiv.find('.numerator').html(idx);
  });
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------
function to remove form elements dynamically
---------------------------------------------^
*/
function removeElement(event) {
  var parentDiv = $(event.delegateTarget);
  let containerDiv = $(this).closest('.container-group');
  if (containerDiv.is('.adult-container')) {
    containerDiv.remove();
    document.getElementById("nbrAdult").value = $('#myForm').find('.adult-container').length;
  }
  if (containerDiv.is('.child-container')) {
    containerDiv.remove();
    document.getElementById("nbrChild").value = $('#myForm').find('.child-container').length;
  }
  // Calculate the new total price
  setTotalPrice();
  updateIds();
  $('#mainform').trigger('setpaypal');
}

/* 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 functions that will be called upon, when user change the list "Nombre"
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function onSelectChange(e) {
  let containerSel = $(this).data('target');
  let nbrValue = this.value;
  let formid = "#myForm";
  let myform = $(formid);
  let items = myform.find(containerSel);
  let itemsCount = items.length;

  // Calculate the delta
  var x = nbrValue - itemsCount;
  // If the delta is negative, delete x
  if (x < 0) {
    let el = items.slice(x).remove();
  } else {
    // Create "x" new
    let j = 0;
    let clonex = $('#holder').find(containerSel).eq(0);
    for (j; j < x; j++) {
      let c = clonex.clone(true);
      c.appendTo(formid);
    }
  }
  updateIds();
  setTotalPrice();
  $('#mainform').trigger('setpaypal');
}

/* 
---------------------------------------------
function that calculate the total price 
---------------------------------------------
*/
function setTotalPrice() {
  document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = document.getElementById("nbrAdult").value * adult_price + document.getElementById("nbrChild").value * child_price;
}
/* 
 ---------------------------------------------
 function that create the Items List formatted for Paypal 
 ---------------------------------------------
 */
function getJsonItemsList() {
  var itemsList = [];
  var selAdultTarget = $('#nbrAdult').data('target');
  var adults = $(selTarget);
  adults.each(function() {
    let item = {
      "name": $(this).find('.type-text') + " " + $(this).find('.numerator').text(),
      "description": $(this).find('.nom-de-famille').val() + "," + $(this).find('.firstname-input').val() + " " + $(this).find('.email-input').val() +
        " " + $(this).find('.tel-input').val(),
      "quantity": "1",
      "price": +adult_price,
      "currency": "EUR"
    };
    itemsList.push(item);
  });

  var selChildTarget = $('#nbrChild').data('target');
  var children = $(selChildTarget);
  children.each(function() {
    let item = {
      "name": $(this).find('.type-text') + " " + $(this).find('.numerator').text(),
      "description": $(this).find('.nom-de-famille').val() + "," + $(this).find('.firstname-input').val(),
      "quantity": "1",
      "price": +child_price,
      "currency": "EUR"
    };
    itemsList.push(item);
  });

  if (!!children.length && !!adults.length) {
    itemsList = "' '";
  }
  return itemsList;
}
/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
functions  that will be called upon, when user click on the Reset Button
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function resetElements() {
  // the select change events do this in a controlled way
  // document.getElementById('myForm').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById("nbrAdult").value = "0";
  document.getElementById("nbrChild").value = "0";
  //when you change the selects they do this, i not needed any more
  //document.getElementById("totalPrice").value = "0";
  // i = 0;
}

function setPayPal() {
  // put other custom stuff here
  let showhide = !$('#myForm').find('.container-group').length;
  // hide if we have none, show if we have some
  $('.length paypal-button-container')
  .toggleClass('hidden', showhide);
}
$(function() {
  $('#myForm').on("click", ".remove-group", removeElement);
  $('#mainform').on('change', "#nbrAdult, #nbrChild", onSelectChange);
  $('#mainform').on('setpaypal', setPayPal);
});
```

```css
.three {
  width: 80%;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.numerator {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.jta-before-form {
  text-align: center;
}

.jta-form-layout {
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 20px;
}

#mainform>.jta-form-content {
  padding: 10px;
}

#myForm {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
}

input {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#myForm .group-container .adult-label,
#myForm .group-container .child-label {
  margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
  display: block;
}

#myForm img {
  float: right;
}

#myForm .group-container .adult-label,
#myForm .group-container .child-label {
  margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
  display: block;
}

#totalPrice {
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#paypal-button-container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="main_content">
    <div class="three">
      <div class="jta-before-form">
        <span id="jta-form-title" class="jta-form-title">
      <h3>reservation</h3></span>
        <div class="">Les champs marqués d’un astérisque * sont obligatoires</div>
      </div>
      <div class="jta-form-layout">
        <form action="#" type="submit" method="get" id="mainform">
          <div class="jta-before-form-content">
            <div class="label">
              <label for="nbrAdult">Nombre Adulte(s)</label>
            </div>
            <select id="nbrAdult" data-target='.adult-container'>
              <option value="0" selected=>0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>

            <div class="label">
              <label for="nbrChild">Nombre Enfant(s)</label>
            </div>
            <select id="nbrChild" data-target='.child-container'>
              <option value="">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="jta-form-content ">
            <span id="myForm"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="jta-after-form-content">Prix Total (Euro)
            <input id="totalPrice" type="text" disabled="disabled" placeholder="0" Size=8 />
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="jta-after-form">
          <div name="button-paypal" id="paypal-button-container">Paypal Pal</div>
        </div>
        <div id="holder" class="hidden">
          <div class="adult-container container-group">
            <hr /><label class="adult-label"><span class="type-text">Adulte</span><span class="numerator"></span></label><input type="text" class="nom-de-famille" placeholder="Nom" name="lastname_adult" required=""><input type="text" class="firstname-input"
              placeholder="Prenom" name="firstname_adult" /><input type="email" class="email-input" placeholder="Email" name="email_adult" /><input type="tel" class="tel-input" placeholder="Tel" name="tel_adult" /><img class="remove-group" src="delete.jpg"
            /></div>
          <div class="child-container container-group">
            <hr /><label class="child-label"><span class="type-text">Enfant</span><span class="numerator"></span></label><input type="text" class="nom-de-famille" placeholder="Nom" name="lastname_child" /><input type="text" placeholder="Prenom" name="firstname_child"
            /><img src="delete.jpg" /></div>
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: this solution is better than mine  now i'm gonna add paypal button "hide" or "show" if the inputs are empty "thanks" for all

Comment: just add to that function `function setPayPal() {` condition on the `toggleClass` - a boolean true/false adds/hides it by using a class/css - it can be ran just by triggering the event `$('#mainform').trigger('setpaypal');`  I edited it just a bit to simplify the use `let showhide` boolean - add more conditions to that

Comment: I don't normally ask for accepts but since you are new, it is customary and helps others if you click that check on the left of the answer that answers your question, and up-vote any that help you or other questions and answers that help you also.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding an event listener to your form that listens for keypresses. The listener will listen to all the dynamically created fields and the input elements in them.

```
var filledInputs = []

$("document").ready(function() {  
    $("#myForm").on("keypress", function(e) {
        var elem = e.target.name + " " + e.target.id
        if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
            if (filledInputs.indexOf(elem) === -1) { filledInputs.push(elem) }
        } else {
            var elemIndex = filledInputs.indexOf(elem) 
            if (elemIndex !== -1) { filledInputs.splice(elemIndex, 1) }
        }
    })
})
```

**EDITTED NOTE:** there are two global variables to keep track of all the available inputs in the form, "allInputElements", and the ones that are currently filled "filledInputs". You need to increase "allInputElements" by the number of inputs elements for a field that's being added to the form during it's creation (4 for adults, 2 for children). The code above will add and remove names of the inputs to filledInputs whenever the user types in one.

```
function onAdultChange() {
    // ...
    if (x < 0) {
        // ... 
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            // ...

            removeElement("myForm", "id_adult_" + max);

            // decrease the global variable when removing input elements
            allInputElements -= 4
        }
    } else {
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            // ...
            document.getElementById("id_adult_" + i).appendChild(g);

            // increase the global variable when adding input elements
            allInputElements += 4
        }
    }
    // ...
}
// ...
function onChildChange() {

    // ...
    if (x < 0) {
        // ...
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            // ...
            removeElement("myForm", "id_child_" + max);

            // decrease the global variable when adding input elements
            allInputElements -= 2
        }
    } else {
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            // ...
            document.getElementById("id_child_" + i).appendChild(g);

            // increase the global variable when adding input elements
            allInputElements += 2
        }
    }
}
```

Aswell as setting allInputElements and filledInputs back to 0 when you clear the form of all input elements:

```
function resetElements() {
    // ...
    allInputElements = 0
    filledInputs = []
}
```

**PS:** if "$(document).ready" doesn't work, move your jQuery  to the very bottom of your HTML body element.

**EDIT:** your options for "disabling" the paypal button are to hide it with css' "display: none" or, the better alternative is to simply check if all inputs are filled before running your paypal code.

```
if (filledInputs.length === allInputElements) {
    // paypal code
}
// else nothing happens
```

Comment: `$("#myForm").on("keypress"` will fire a LOT, on the input of names, emails etc. when things change via code it does not fire, and it does not fire on a mouse click. or a select click or a "select" change.